# Cover inactive windows with GUI, Solutions to Variable Coordinates (AHK)

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey, coordinate-systems

I collapse all my windows to title bars when not active. I want to cover these inactive windows with different color GUIs. The GUI will only need minimal functionality, just a way to color-code title bars when collapsed, and inactive. That way, I can tell what's what much easier when I look at a desktop full of title bars.

Although I know I have the correct coordinates stored as variables, the gui doesn't show up at all if I specify coordinates as numbers, or as variables. But if I don't specify any coordinates, the GUI appears in the middle of the screen.

This just seems like a combination of

-settimer, and a timer that updates the coordinates when the window moves.

-alwaysontop(ish) of a specific window for each gui(could use some help here, Looking to apply winset, top to a GUI when it's associated window is inactive, but also remain under any newly active window (to keep the GUI visible when looking at the desktop).

-using the corresponding window's y coordinate to know how high to place the GUI(main issue, although I know I have the correct coordinates stored as variables)

-displaying a different color for each GUI.

-The GUI should span across the entire screen width, and be 1/17 the screen height (about the height of the title bar with my screen/resolution).

-winhide a window's gui when it's associated window is active, and winshow when inactive

```
    #SingleInstance,Force
    WinGetPos , X_SciTEWindow, Y_SciTEWindow, Width_SciTEWindow, Height_SciTEWindow, ahk_class SciTEWindow ;I don't even need the X_SciTEWindow, because the bars will all be aligned at x0, but it's there... 
    SysGet, aScreenHeight, 1 
    bar_height := Round(aScreenHeight / 17)
    Gui, Color, aqua,FFB1B1
    Gui, Show, w%A_ScreenWidth% h%bar_height%, SomeStupidBar
    WinSet, Style,  -20xC40000
    Winmove, %SomeStupidBar%,  x0, y%Y_SciTEWindow%, w%A_ScreenWidth%, h%bar_height%
    MsgBox, Time to move the window to x0, y%Y_SciTEWindow%, w%A_ScreenWidth%, h%bar_height%
    Winmove, %SomeStupidBar%,  x0, y%Y_SciTEWindow%, w%A_ScreenWidth%, h%bar_height%
    return
    Esc::ExitApp


    SetTimer, ShowGui, 500
    ShowGui:    
    IfWinNotExist, ahk_class AutohotkeyGUI
    {
    Gui, +Owner%WinID% +Border +ToolWindow 
    Gui, Show, NoActivate x%X% y%Y% w51 h431, %GuiTitle%
    }
    else
    {
    WinWaitActive, ahk_class SciTEWindow
    WinGetPos, X_SciTEWindow, Y_SciTEWindow,,, ahk_class Notepad
    WinGet, WinID, ID, ahk_class SciTEWindow,,,
    IfWinNotExist, ahk_class AutohotkeyGUI
    WinGetPos, %SomeStupidBar%, , , ,  ahk_class AutohotkeyGUI
    If %SomeStupidBar%<>X - 56
    WinMove, ahk_class AutohotkeyGUI,  X - 56
    }
    return
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I collapse all my windows to title bars when not active". What do you mean by "collapse"? How do you manage it?

Comment: @user3419297 I meant to say, "resized to be extremely, short, only as tall as a title bar" instead of "collapsed". 

I have a secondary .ahk that will minimize any newly inactive window, hold down alt + tab for me, let me choose a new window, then maximize it. 

With the addition of color coded title bars, i would not  need to use alt-tab in this process, because everything would be easy to see. I could just use my secondary .ahk file described above to easily see all running programs and know which is which without reading little print on skinny title bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

Gui, SciTE: +Owner -Caption
Gui, SciTE: Color, aqua 

Gui, Notepad: +Owner -Caption
Gui, Notepad: Color, red

SysGet, aScreenHeight, 1 
bar_height := Round(aScreenHeight / 17)

SetTimer, ShowGui, 500
return

Esc::ExitApp

ShowGui:
If !WinExist("ahk_class SciTEWindow") ; means "NOT"
    Gui, SciTE: Cancel
else
{
    WinGetPos, X_SciTE, Y_SciTE,,, ahk_class SciTEWindow
    If X_SciTE >= 0
    Gui, SciTE:  Show, NoActivate x%X_SciTE% y%Y_SciTE% w51 h%bar_height%, SciTEWindow
}
If !WinExist("ahk_class Notepad")
    Gui, Notepad: Cancel
else
{
    WinGetPos, X_Notepad, Y_Notepad,,, ahk_class Notepad
    If X_Notepad >= 0
    Gui, Notepad:  Show, NoActivate x%X_Notepad% y%Y_Notepad% w51 h%bar_height%, Notepad
}
return

#If WinActive("ahk_class AutoHotkeyGUI")

    ~*LButton Up::
        WinGetTitle, ActiveTitle, A         
        WinActivate, ahk_class %ActiveTitle%    
    return

#If
```